# Create a document using CMIS in Javascript

Tags: sapui5, cmis, opencmis

I am trying to create a document in the SAP Document Center of HCP using Javascript and I can not. SAP Document Center uses the CMIS protocol for communication with other applications. I have been able to connect from my SAPUI5 application with the SAP Document Center. I have also managed to create a folder as follows:

```
createFolder: function(repositoryId, parentFolderId, folderName) {
        var data = {
            objectId: parentFolderId,
            cmisaction: "createFolder",
            "propertyId[0]": "cmis:name",
            "propertyValue[0]": folderName,
            "propertyId[1]": "cmis:objectTypeId",
            "propertyValue[1]": "cmis:folder"
        };

        $.ajax("/destination/document/mcm/json/" + repositoryId + "/root", {
            type: "POST",
            data: data
        }).done(function() {
            MessageBox.show("Folder with name " + folderName + " successfully created.");
        }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
            MessageBox.show("Creation of folder with name " + folderName + " failed. XHR response message: " + jqXHR.responseJSON.message);
        });
    },
```

However, I find it impossible to create a document. I can not find an internet sample for the CMIS "createDocument" method. There are many examples for Java but nothing to do with Javascript. I do not know what the structure of the data to send. The code is as follows:

```
createDocument: function(repositoryId, parentFolderId, documentName, content) {
            /** 
             * 'content' contains the whole document converted to a base64 string like this:
             * "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUNJeLjz9MNCjIxNCAwIG9iag08P..."
             */
            var data = {
                objectId: parentFolderId,
                cmisaction: "createDocument",
                contentStream: content,
                "propertyId[0]": "cmis:name",
                "propertyValue[0]": documentName,
                "propertyId[1]": "cmis:objectTypeId",
                "propertyValue[1]": "cmis:document"
            };

            $.ajax("/destination/document/mcm/json/" + repositoryId + "/root", {
                type: "POST",
                data: data
            }).done(function() {
                MessageBox.show("Document with name " + documentName + " successfully created.");
            }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
                MessageBox.show("Creation of document with name " + documentName + " failed. XHR response message: " + jqXHR.responseJSON.message);
            });
        },
```

With this I create a file record within the SAP Document Center but it does not take the data. An unformatted file is created, when it should have the format sent (PDF, txt, Excel, Doc, ...).

Does anyone know how to do it?

Regards.

**Links of interest:**

CMIS Standard
http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.html#x1-1710002

Usage examples for Java (not Javascript)
http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html

Comment: Have you tried to set the content type to 'multipart/form-data' ?

Answer (score 1):

I have been through a similar problem. My solution is to change it from base64 to a FormData approach, so I got the file input value instead of the content base64 string. It worked fine.

```
 this.createObject = function (fileInput, objectName,folderId, cbOk, cbError) {

        if (!folderId) {
            folderId = _this.metadata.rootFolderId;
        }

        var documentData = {
            'propertyId[1]': 'cmis:objectTypeId',
            'propertyValue[1]': 'cmis:document',
            'propertyId[0]': 'cmis:name',
            'propertyValue[0]': objectName,
            'objectId': folderId,
            'cmisaction': 'createDocument',
            'content' : fileInput
        };

        var formData = new FormData();

        jQuery.each(documentData, function(key, value){
            formData.append(key, value);
        });


        $.ajax({
            url: _this.metadata.actionsUrl,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                cbOk(data);
            },
            error: function(err){
                cbError(err);
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view.xml add following lines.

```
<FileUploader id="fileUploader" 
              name="myFileUpload" 
              uploadUrl="/cmis/root"
              width="400px" 
              tooltip="Upload your file to the local server" 
              uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete" 
              change='onChangeDoc'/>
```

the upload url will be url to the neo destination. In the **neo.app.json** add the following lines.

```
{
    "path": "/cmis",
    "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "documentservice"
    },
    "description": "documentservice"
}
```

In the **controller.js** add the following lines of code.

```
if (!oFileUploader.getValue()) {
    sap.m.MessageToast.show("Choose a file first");
    return;
}

var data = {
    'propertyId[0]': 'cmis:objectTypeId',
    'propertyValue[0]': 'cmis:document',
    'propertyId[1]': 'cmis:name',
    'propertyValue[1]': file.name,
    'cmisaction': 'createDocument'
};

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('datafile', new Blob([file]));
jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
    formData.append(key, value);
});

$.ajax('/cmis/root', {
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
        sap.m.MessageToast.show("File Uploaded Successfully");              
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(error) {
        sap.m.MessageBox.error("File Uploaded Unsuccessfully. Save is not possible. " + error.responseJSON.message);
    }
});
```

In the neo cloud, maintain the url for following configuration in destination tab. `https://testdaasi328160trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/TestDaaS/cmis/json/repo-id`

repo-id will be your repository key.

this will solve the problem. You will be able to upload and the document.